# The integral symbol with a transverse bar

Tags: symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to look up a symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol)

How to put in .tex the integral symbol with a transverse bar?

It generally refers to the mean value of a function on a ball or others sets.

```
$$average(\int_{E})f =\frac{1}{volume(E)}\int_E f$$
```

Comment: If you're actually using LaTeX and not TeX, see [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5764)